# Why one sided limit here?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider

[image]

and then

[image]

This is from Abbott, Understanding Analysis. Why **one-sided** limit? It does not seem to exist from either side.

So why not just say '' the limit $\lim_{x \to 0} g_2'(x)$ does not exist''?

Thanks for any insight into this.

Comment: Maybe is an obtuse form of saying that neither lateral limit exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reformulation: neither the limit of $g'(x)$ when $x\to0$, $x\gt0$, nor the limit of $g'(x)$ when $x\to0$, $x\lt0$, exist.

"One-sided" refers to limits restricted to one side of $0$, thus, either to $x\gt0$ or to $x\lt0$. "As one sided limits" (plural) would already be a better formulation.

**Edit:** That neither the limit from the left nor the limit from the right exist is more informative than the fact that the (full) limit does not exist. For example, the function $x\mapsto\mathbf 1_{x\geqslant0}$ has no limit at $0$ but this discontinuity is not essential since the limits from the left and from the right exist.

Comment: But why is it important to restrict to limits from one side at all? Why is it not an appropriate formulation to just say '' the limit $\lim_{x \to 0}g_2' (x)$ does not exist''?

Comment: It would be correct as well, but less informative, see Edit.

Comment: Great insightful answer, thank you!